# matplotlib yaxis strange dont want every value shown in yaxis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot a simple scatter plot, previously the codes below will give the plot that I want, but now when I changed to Linux, the plot is strange:

```
            data = np.loadtxt(fname,delimiter='\t')
            X = data[:, 0]
            Y = data[:, 1]
            plt.plot(X, Y,'o')
            plt.show()
```

The plot generated in Linux:
[strange plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNHpF.png)

It seems like something is wrong with the yaxis, I don't want
every point's y value to be shown in yaxis.

The correct curve should not be a straight line, but something like this:
[correct plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mA41D.png)

Anyone can help? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: sorry I have solved this problem,

Comment: I added "Y = ["{:0.3f}".format(i) for i in Y.tolist()]" before plot(), after removing this line, the plot is correct